# How can I make variable from HealthKit query accessible outside function?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I have been given access to HealthStore and I successfully print the data to the console.  However I need to access the data outside the function, which I have created a singleton for and it works fine.  Only trouble is, the data from the sample query (performQueryForHrSamples()) does not persist outside of the function, meaning that when I call the variable beatsPerMin outside the function I get nil.  The variable is initiated as var beatsPerMin:Double!

I have tried to "unnest" the function to find a way to create a -> return, but have not succeeded.

Can someone please help me find a way to make this variable accessible outside of perfromQueryForHRSamples()?  Maybe I can save the data to CoreData, like this: ([Can I save value in a completion Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27074421/can-i-save-value-in-a-completion-handler)) ?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var beatsPerMin:Double!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        somefunc1()
        perfromQueryForHRSamples()
        somefunc3()
    }

    func somefunc1() {

        ....... {
                (success, error) in
                if success {
                    println("success")
                } else {
                    println("cancelled \(error)")
                }
        }
    }


    **func perfromQueryForHRSamples**() {
        let heartRateSample = HKSampleType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate)
        let sampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(
            sampleType: heartRateSample,
            predicate: nil,
            limit: 0,
            sortDescriptors: nil) {
                (sampleQuery, samples, error) in

                for sample in samples as [HKQuantitySample]
                {
                    **self.beatsPerMin**  = sample.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(self.heartRateUnit)
                    println("Query output: \(self.beatsPerMin)")
                }
        }

        self.healthStore.executeQuery(sampleQuery)



    } 

    func somefunc3() {
        println("\(beatsPerMin)")

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ... I discovered that my functions were sometimes not evaluated unless they were "called"...

FYI, no function will be evaluated until it is called from another function.

If `somefunc2` produces a `Double` as output, then it should output a `Double`.

```
func somefunc2() -> Double {
    var result: Double = 0.0
    // figure out what the result should be and assign it to result
    return result
}
```

If `somefunc3` requires a `Double` as input, then it should accept a `Double` as a parameter.

```
func somefunc3(z: Double) {
    // do stuff with z
    println("\(z)")
}
```

Then you can connect the two functions through the value by:

```
let z = somefunc2()
somefunc3(z)
```

or if you want to be "clever".

```
somefunc3(somefunc2())
```

At this point in your programming education, I suggest you mess about in the playground more until you get a feel for how functions interact with each other.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, your answer clarified much of what I have learned! Very succinct and useful response